# element.nodeName not defined for a html element created using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I created a new HTML element using jQuery.

```
var v=jQuery('<p>Hello</p>);
```

But when I try to get the nodeName of the new element,

```
v.nodeName.toLowerCase();
```

I get error, saying that nodeName is not defined. What is wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`v` is the jQuery object that contains the dom element not the real dom element, you must do:

```
v[0].nodeName.toLowerCase();
```